Where can I find a benchmark for long-term interest rates in the U.S., given that the Fed primarily sets short-term rates?
I always assumed “interest rates” were set by the Fed across the board, without distinguishing between short- and long-term rates. However, from the top response to a previous question of mine, I learned that while the Fed controls short-term rates, long-term rates are driven more by market expectations.
What’s a common benchmark for long-term interest rates in the U.S., and where can I find or calculate this rate?

I don't think a benchmark exists as such. History is easy to obtain, but future results are contingent upon future history. It's up to you to determine your degree of confidence in projecting the trends, or your degree of confidence in someone else's projection. If anyone was able to do this reliably, rates would adjust to allow for that.

The US Treasury publishes a daily "yield curve" based on the prices that people are paying for Treasury bonds in the secondary market (or directly from the Treasury when they have auctions).
While it's true that they only set the rate that banks get when they borrow funds from the Fed overnight, they do also set the actual interest rate that you get from buying a longer term bond (i.e. if you buy a 5% 10Y bond, that 5% is guaranteed). It's the price that you pay for those bonds (which determines the overall yield that is set by the market. For example, if you buy a 5% bond for less than its face value, you'll get more than a 5% yield (the 5% coupon plus the gain in price when the bond matures). That yield is what is published by the Treasury.
If you want to know what yield you can expect from buying a 30Y Govt bond regardless of its coupon (interest) rate, you can look it up in the yield curve.
